# JSONField getting saved as string django

Tags: python, django-jsonfield

I have a django model like below:

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
class SCUser(User):
    address = JSONField(blank=True,null=True)
```

When I save a json in this address it gets saved as string.
Here is a code snippet:

```
appuser.address = {"state":""}
appuser.save()
```

Now if I try to retrieve appuser.address it gives me

```
>>>appuser.address
>>>u'{"state":""}'
>>>appuser.save()
>>>appuser.address
>>>u'"{\\"state\\":\\"\\"}"'
```

And it gets recursive.
What am I missing here?

**Edit:**
The AppUser inherits from SCUser model.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem when I am using a non-Autofield key as the model's primary key and I found some issues which is still open on github related to this problem.

https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield/issues/92

https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield/issues/101

I solved this problem by define a pk property in the model. I don't known is there any side effects by using this solution.

```
class SCUser(User):
    ....

    @property
    def pk(self):
        return self.id  # your pk
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try:

```
appuser.address = {"state":""}
appuser.save()
appuser.get_data_json()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Comment: there is not such a method as `get_data_json()`